# OFDM with CSMA/CA

Tags: wireless, multiplexer, wifi

Most Wifi standards (e.g. 802.11a) use OFDM for orthogonal frequency multiplexing, i.e. assigning different subcarriers/frequencies to different users. On the other hand, it says [CSMA/CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance#Usage) is used to manage the access in the time domain and avoid collisions of two users transmitting on the same frequency at the same time.

Why do I need both? If I have different frequencies for different users, that should suffice to avoid collisions. Or are these frequencies not exclusively assigned to a single user but to a group of users? Or is in fact CSMA/CA only used in Wifi standards without OFDM?

Comment: I do not see why you think that Wifi assigns subchannels to different users. Wifi is OFDM but **not** OFDMA. In fact Wifi does almost nothing to allow simultaneous usage of bandwidth. Other standards that do use OFDMA do both frequency **and** time sharing to allow for more simultaneous users.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the difference between OFDM and OFDMA. So in OFDM the subcarriers are not used to separate users but just to increase the number of symbols that can be sent simultaneously, i.e. the data rate?

Comment: That is exactly the reason to use OFDM, a higher datarate (at the cost of needing a higher signal-noise ratio)

Comment: @FakeMoustache Why not copy/paste your comment to an answer?

Comment: Sure why not :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why you think that Wifi assigns subchannels to different users.

Wifi is [OFDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing) but not [OFDMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiple_access). In fact Wifi does almost nothing to allow simultaneous usage of bandwidth. Other standards that do use OFDMA do both frequency and time sharing to allow for more simultaneous users (Multiple Access).

In Wifi OFDM is used only to increase the datarate at the cost of needing a higher signal/noise ratio. This explains why you get a lower datarate in an environment with a lot of  Wifi activity, the system switches back to a lower datarate so that it can cope with a worse signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Just to clarify: Based on the SNR, a suitable modulation is picked which determines the data rate?

Comment: That is correct.